# Migration of SharePoint to Confluence

Tags: sharepoint-2010, confluence

Does anybody know an easy way to migrate a SharePoint 2010 data to Confluence 6.3?

Comment: Looking for documents such as word, pdf, xls, css etc

Comment: This seems more relevant to [su] than [so].

Comment: (What *are* you trying to achieve with the `Blockquote`s?)

Answer (score 0):

You might explore [Enterprise Bridge](http://caseagile.com/products/enterprise-bridge/sharepoint-to-confluence-migration/) which fully automates migration of content from SharePoint 2010 to Confluence 6.3.